# .net core calling wcf service - SecurityAccessDeniedException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-core-3.1

Receiving the following error message regardless of basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding in .net core 3.1:

```
 SecurityAccessDeniedException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, string action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ref ProxyRpc rpc)
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(string action, object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy+TaskCreator+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

this is the code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;  
var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("soapendpoint");
var client = new Client(binding, address);

var cf = client.ChannelFactory;
cf.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
cf.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
var channel = cf.CreateChannel();

var response = channel.GetPatientAsync();
```

i am not after a solution but some pointers on either what am i doing wrong here or what else should i try to figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out the reason for the error is because WCF service has WS Policies and two of those policies are not supported in .NET Core. One is sp:encryptedsecuritytoken and other is sp:trust

Answer (score 0):

The type of binding and the sort of credential should be consistent with the server’s configuration.
I suggest you generate a client proxy to call the remote service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
With this tool, we can generate a proxy and get a proper configuration corresponding with the server configuration. afterward, we can make an invocation to the service.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            var result = client.TestAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
```

Since the tool also generates the service contract on the client-side, we could also change a way to call the remote service according to the service configuration generated in the `Reference.cs` file.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:21011");
            ChannelFactory<IService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var result1 = service.TestAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result1.Result);
```

All we should pay attention to is that the type of binding and the security type should be consistent with the one on the server. Therefore, the first important thing is that we should find out the server configuration and apply it on the client-side.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exits.

Comment: i had already generated a proxy class but how would i find the bindings used on the server and also the binding supported by .net core/

Comment: Check the Reference.cs file located in the ServiceReference1 namespace. it contains the proxy class, Service contract, binding type. when we instantiate a client proxy, these configurations will be automatically used.

Comment: it just takes an object of System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding. there is nothing else in the Reference.cs file.

Comment: There is a possibility resulting in that the reference.cs file is empty. That is the WCF service created by the Webhttpbinding by default doesn’t support the invocation with a proxy.  the file will generate nothing. the service with webhttpbinding is Rest API. We need to send an HTTP request by using an HTTP library, the request usually attached with HTTP verb and request body. Please ask your service provider for more details.

Comment: found out the reason for the error is because WCF service has WS Policies and two of those policies are not supported in .NET Core. One is sp:encryptedsecuritytoken and other is sp:trust

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `ChannelFactory` rather than getting the channel factory from a client in case anything is cached by the client:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<SoapInterfaceType>(binding, remoteAddress);
channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "";
channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "";
var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: found out the reason for the error is because WCF service has WS Policies and two of those policies are not supported in .NET Core. One is sp:encryptedsecuritytoken and other is sp:trust

Comment: @Baahubali Good finding. Maybe you want post that as your own answer just so that people can easily find it.

Comment: yea i have not been able to overcome that problem yet. i am trying to figure out how to manually write a class that would satisfy those policies within .net core. here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970867/net-core-consuming-wcf-service-with-ws-policy-assertions